# How can I centralize enviroment information in flutter

Tags: flutter, environment-variables

I'm trying to learn flutter and I came into a problem.
I want to create a application that I can easily swap some texts and images url's only by changing a file, so I can make kinda like a universal boilerplate.

For example:

Before:

`Image.asset('happy_person');`

After:

```
// On the same file as before
 Image.asset(LOGIN_IMAGE);

//In another file
 LOGIN_IMAGE = 'happy_person'
```

I thought of a .ENV file, but I don't think this would be the correct approach since the texts and images in my application will scale quite a bit, besides I still don't know how to implement a .ENV in a flutter application ( if someone has some useful links I appreciate it).

To be honest I know that a class with a bunch of static variables would solve it but I don't find that pretty haha ( if this is the only way to go, feel free to point out)

If anyone knows how to make my problem a little bit easier or even solve it, would love to read about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `dart-define-from-file`. A full blog post explaining how to use it is here but basically you define a config.json file and pass it to Flutter at build/run time:

https://itnext.io/flutter-3-7-and-a-new-way-of-defining-compile-time-variables-f63db8a4f6e2

```
flutter run --dart-define-from-file=<use-define-config.json>
```